# How do I export all open files into PNGs and have every window close in the end?

Tags: export, adobe-illustrator

Last year, I had help with making an Illustrator script that hides the text layer of all open files and saves every one, but I am wondering how to add code that exports all the files into PNGs (to the size of the artboard) and close all the open windows in the end.

I have been doing this just by using a Batch PNG export action in Illustrator and then manually closing everything, but I figured it would be more efficient to have it all included in one script.
Thank you anyone in advance for helping out!

```
for(var i=0;i<app.documents.length;i++)
{
        var oDoc=app.documents[i];
        for(var j=0;j<oDoc.layers.length; j++)
            {
                if(oDoc.layers[j].name=="text")
                {
                    oDoc.layers[j].visible=false;
                 }
                 if(oDoc.layers[j].name=="text2")
                {
                    oDoc.layers[j].visible=false;
                 }
           }

}

#target illustrator

function test(){

 

  for(var i=0; i<app.documents.length; i++){

    app.documents[i].activate();

    app.activeDocument.save();

  };

 

};

test();
```

I have been looking for a solution but I haven't seen anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I merged the script that coolshrimp suggested with another script that applied the script to an entire directory and it worked smoothly!
This is the script I merged it with ->
[Running a script on all .ai files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71069458/running-a-script-on-all-ai-files-in-a-directory?rq=1)

```
    #target illustrator



// Function to unlock all locked layers in the document
function unlockAllLayers(doc) {
    function unlockLayers(layer) {
        layer.locked = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < layer.layers.length; i++) {
            unlockLayers(layer.layers[i]);
        }
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < doc.layers.length; j++) {
        unlockLayers(doc.layers[j]);
    }
}

// Function to remove all layers containing text items
function removeTextLayers(doc) {
    for (var j = doc.layers.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        var layer = doc.layers[j];
        var textItems = layer.textFrames;
        
        if (textItems.length > 0) {
            layer.remove();
        }
    }
}

// Function to export the active document as a PNG with the same name
function exportPNG(doc) {
    var pngOptions = new ExportOptionsPNG24();
    pngOptions.artBoardClipping = true;
    pngOptions.antiAliasing = true;
    pngOptions.transparency = true;

    var file = new File(doc.path + "/" + doc.name.replace(/\.[^\.]*$/, '') + ".png");
    doc.exportFile(file, ExportType.PNG24, pngOptions);
}

function main() {

    var folder = Folder.selectDialog('Please, select the folder');
    if (!(folder instanceof Folder)) return;

    var files = folder.getFiles('*.ai');
    if (files.length == 0) {
        alert('Folder doesn\'t content AI files');
        return;
    }

    var i = files.length;
    while (i--) {
        var doc = app.open(files[i]);
        unlockAllLayers(doc); // Add this line to unlock all layers
        removeTextLayers(doc);
        exportPNG(doc);
        doc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
    }

    alert(files.length + ' files were processed');
}

main();
```

I also made an alternate version using the script I was given last year that hides text layers with specific layer names.
This replaces the part that starts with "// Function to remove all layers containing text items"

```
// Function to remove all layers containing text items
function removeTextLayers(doc) {
    for (var j = doc.layers.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        var layer = doc.layers[j];
        var textItems = layer.textFrames;
        
            {
                if(doc.layers[j].name=="text1")
                {
                    doc.layers[j].visible=false;
                 }
                 if(doc.layers[j].name=="text2")
                {
                    doc.layers[j].visible=false;
                 }
                 if(doc.layers[j].name=="text3")
                {
                    doc.layers[j].visible=false;
                 }
           }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Script hides layers with specified names (e.g., "text" and "text2") before saving, exporting to PNG, and closing each open document.

```
#target illustrator

// Function to export the active document as a PNG with the same name
function exportPNG(doc) {
    var pngOptions = new ExportOptionsPNG24();
    pngOptions.artBoardClipping = true;
    pngOptions.antiAliasing = true;
    pngOptions.transparency = true;

    var file = new File(doc.path + "/" + doc.name.replace(/\.[^\.]*$/, '') + ".png");
    doc.exportFile(file, ExportType.PNG24, pngOptions);
}

// Function to hide the specified layers
function hideTextLayers(doc, layerNames) {
    for (var j = 0; j < doc.layers.length; j++) {
        if (layerNames.includes(doc.layers[j].name)) {
            doc.layers[j].visible = false;
        }
    }
}    

// Main script
for (var i = 0; i < app.documents.length; i++) {
    var doc = app.documents[i];
    hideTextLayers(doc, ["text", "text2"]);
    doc.save();
    //exportPNG(doc); / Commented out this line to disable PNG export
    doc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
}
```

Script removes all layers containing text items before saving, exporting to PNG, and closing each open document.

```
#target illustrator

// Function to export the active document as a PNG with the same name
function exportPNG(doc) {
    var pngOptions = new ExportOptionsPNG24();
    pngOptions.artBoardClipping = true;
    pngOptions.antiAliasing = true;
    pngOptions.transparency = true;

    var file = new File(doc.path + "/" + doc.name.replace(/\.[^\.]*$/, '') + ".png");
    doc.exportFile(file, ExportType.PNG24, pngOptions);
}

// Function to remove all layers containing text items
function removeTextLayers(doc) {
    for (var j = doc.layers.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        var layer = doc.layers[j];
        var textItems = layer.textFrames;
        
        if (textItems.length > 0) {
            layer.remove();
        }
    }
}

// Main script
for (var i = 0; i < app.documents.length; i++) {
    var doc = app.documents[i];
    removeTextLayers(doc);
    doc.save();
    //exportPNG(doc); // Commented out this line to disable PNG export
    doc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for you help!

For the first script, I get an error saying:
`Error 24: layerNames.includes is not a function (this is a translation of Japanese text so I don't know what this is in the English version)
-> if (layerNames.includes(doc.layers[j].name)) {`

For the second script, it seems to work well but it only affects one open document and not all open documents and only on unlocked layers.

Comment: For Error 24: how are you running it in batch mode?
batch mode to process multiple files at once, you don't need to save the document as a PNG before closing it. you can remove that line "exportPNG(doc);".


Did you use the first option if so you specify the layer names. "["text", "text2"]"

Comment: I edited my original answer after i re-read your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a function to unlock all layers.
Then call it in the main (for) loop

```
// Function to unlock all locked layers in the document
function unlockAllLayers(doc) {
    function unlockLayers(layer) {
        layer.locked = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < layer.layers.length; i++) {
            unlockLayers(layer.layers[i]);
        }
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < doc.layers.length; j++) {
        unlockLayers(doc.layers[j]);
    }
}
```

Then, call this function in the main script before calling removeTextLayers(doc) to ensure all layers are unlocked:

```
// Main script
for (var i = 0; i < app.documents.length; i++) {
    var doc = app.documents[i];
    unlockAllLayers(doc); // Add this line to unlock all layers
    removeTextLayers(doc);
    doc.save();
    exportPNG(doc);
    doc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
}
```

Comment: Hello! I apologize for the wait!

Thank you so much for your help! I tried the new updated script and added in the new functions and tried it with three open .AI files. It seemed to be working well, but the third file's PNG would save over the second file's PNG for some reason. 

I couldn't figure out what was the issue, so I merged the script with a script that applied to an entire directory (instead of applying to open files) and it seemed to work well! I'll post what worked below.